# Using t translation on props in Vue with vue i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, translation, vue-i18n

I would like to translate the titles that are passed to my component via props. However I assume because my strings are being passed via props they are not being translated like the rest of my code. Below you will find my current 2 components that I am working with:

Parent Component:

```
  `<setting-section
    :title="$t('Random Text 1')"
    :description="$t('Random Text 2')"
  >`
```

In the Child:

```
`<template>
  <div class="flex grid w-full">
    <div class="divider mr-4 mt-5" />
    <div class="header col-2">
      <div class="title text-primary">{{ title }}</div>
      <div class="description text-xs">{{ description }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex col-10" v-if="!isLoading">
      <slot />
    </div>
    <div class="flex col-10" v-else>
      <Skeleton height="5rem" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Menu',
    props: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
    },
  };
</script>`
```

How ever if I do add the below variation it obviously wont work.

```
`<template>
  <div class="flex grid w-full">
    <div class="header col-2">
      <div class="title text-primary">{{ $t('title')}} </div>
      <div class="description text-xs">{{ description }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>`
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you write the translation for `Random Text 1`?

Comment: It's supposed to work, as long as there are no reactivity problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your both the solutions should work as we always configured `VueI18n` at global level. Hence, translation literals always accessible from any nested component.

Live Demo as per both the use cases **:**

```js
Vue.component('child-one', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>'
});

Vue.component('child-two', {
  template: `<p>{{ $t('message') }}</p>`
});

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: {
    "ja": {
      "message": "こんにちは、世界"
    },
    "en": {
      "message": "Hello World"
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  i18n,
  data() {
    return {
      locale: "ja"
    }
  },
  watch: {
    locale(newLocale) {
      this.$i18n.locale = newLocale;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@8.8.2/dist/vue-i18n.min.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" value="ja" v-model="locale" />Japanese</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="en" v-model="locale" />English</label>
  </div>

  <h3>Passing translated string from parent</h3>
  <child-one :childmsg="$t('message')"></child-one>
  
  <h3>Transaltions happens in child component itself</h3>
  <child-two></child-two>
</main>
```